# How to create a Boolean Numpy Array using fancy indexing

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following dummy array:

```
>>> arr

[[0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1]]
```

I also have some "mutations" I would like to incorporate into my array, at the following positions (note these are generated randomly each time, so I cannot just set them manually):

```
row = [0 4 3] 
col = [11 10 7]
```

I know I can target each (row, col) pair using fancy indexing with `arr[row, col] = -3` (for example, set those elements to -3).

However, what I want to do is a bitwise NOT - aka something like this:

```
arr[row, col] = ~arr
```

I tried using np.where(), but it won't accept `arr[row, col]` b/c it doesn't generate a boolean array.

Any suggestions? How can I create a boolean array to use as a where conditional

(*also yes, I know I can make an array of all zeros in the same shape as arr and then set those positions to 1's and use that as a mask - I'd love something cleaner tho*)

Thanks!

Comment: Does `arr[row, col] = ~arr[row, col]` produce your expected output?

Comment: Or, using `ufunc.at`, `np.bitwise_not.at(arr, (row, col))`.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem To my total surprise, yes, it does. I had to do `pop[row, col] = ~arr[row, col] & 1` because I'm using unsigned ints, but yeah that works perfectly. Could you explain *why* that works? Also if you post your answer as a solution I'll accept it.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Your second one worked too! Again I had add an &1 for the uints:  `np.bitwise_not.at(arr, (row, col)); arr &= 1` but otherwise it's perfect! Totally overlooked `ufunc.at`

Comment: You may want to convert `arr` to `dtype=np.bool` to avoid extra work with `& 1`.  As to why this works, to assign to `arr[row, col]` you need a 1d array of the same length, so `~arr[row, col]` sounds like a natural choice. The `at` solution will probably be a _bit_ more efficient.